# determine what time I connected to the vpn from command line

Tags: networking, command-line, vpn, powershell, ip

How do I find what time I connected to a vpn using powershell or cmd?

I would only be doing this when there's an active connection to the vpn and would only need the time that I established the current connection. (The idea is that I want to trigger a script only if the vpn is connected and was connected recently within the last ten minutes). It doesn't have to for my uses, but I bet any solution would work generally for determining the time a connection was established for any internet connection, not just a vpn connection.

I'm running Windows 10 Enterprise. The VPN is my employer's so I don't have access to logs on the server, so I want to do this client side. I also don't have administrator privileges on the computer.

I've tried `ipconfig` and `netstat` including with some of their options, but haven't found anything that returns the time the connection was established.

I'm sorry, this is probably super easy to do, but I haven't found the answer yet. Thank you!

Comment: Look in the VPN logs?

Comment: Did you check Event Viewer?

Comment: Are you using the Windows built in VPN client/settings or are using a third party VPN app like Fortinet/OpenVPN/GlobalVPN/AnyConnect/NetExtender ?

Comment: I didn't even know about the event viewer until now :D Thank you all for the help! I believe my vpn is a third party app, and the code below worked for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the Built in windows VPN client, you can search the event log as the other comments have suggested. Here is what it looks like in powershell:

```
$vpnlog = Get-eventlog -LogName Application -Message *VPN*  | select Timegenerated -first 1
$vpnTime = $vpnlog.TimeGenerated.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
$currentTime = Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"
$timeSpan = New-TimeSpan –Start $vpnTime –End $currentTime
$uptime = $timeSpan.ToString("dd' days 'hh' hours 'mm' minutes 'ss' seconds'")
Write-Host "Uptime is: $uptime"
```

Output: `Uptime is: 01 days 13 hours 33 minutes 26 seconds`

Comment: It worked for me, thank you so much!