Which methods are available to reliably auto-disconnect any VPN connection in Windows?
While Windows VPN has an option to disconnection it's connection after a certain amount of idle time, I have never found this to actually work in any reliable manner.
How do I force the windows VPN connection to forcibly disconnect after a certain period after it establishes a connection regardless of network activity?
Ideally looking for a solution that would force any VPN connection (e.g. Palo Alto's GlobalProtect client) to drop after it has been connected for a defined period of time. I often run into the issue where I connect to a worksite and forget to disconnect the VPN.

Does this work?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49194774

You could probably use Get-VpnConnection -AllUserConnection to find all VPN connections, filter by connected status and use rasdial $vpnName /DISCONNECT to disconnect. To find out how long a VPN connection has been active, maybe this might help: Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Source RasClient or https://superuser.com/a/1765380/167187

You'll have to turn off automatic re-connect if you want your 'connection' interval to have any meaning.

Consider rephrasing your question. Questions asking that we recommend tools/utilities are explicitly off topic. You are not really looking for a tool: You are looking for a solution to a problem. So remove the parts about wanting us to suggest a utility, and instead simply ask for help solving the specific problem you're facing.
